# css not getting loaded in flask webpage?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, siteminder

In our `flask based web application` 'contact page' we using style-sheets for the appearance of website. 
if we click on contact hyperlink it navigate us to contact.html page.

here is the sample snippet of file '/static/Templates/contact.html'

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}" />
<head>
```

recently i applied the `siteminder(SSO)` authentication to our website, all pages are working as expected but when we click contact page `hyperlink`
giving build error as shown below.

**error trace as like this**

```
raise builderror(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('routes.static', {'filename':'main.css'}, None)
```

I am not able to find out the reason for build error, `SSO` is blocking to build the url?
thanks in advance

Comment: Is that error copied and pasted here?  It says it can't find file `main.csss`.  You have too many `s`s in the filename call.  Look through the code to see if you accidentally typed `main.csss` somewhere and change that.

Comment: Its not actual error its part of it, thanks for pointing typo.